# java.net.UnknownHostException in Android when trying to reach graph.facebook.com

Tags: android, facebook

I have an android app, and I try to get information from Facebook. I use an http get request and actually worked out great in one instance (when I try to get a user mutual friends list).

However, I have attempted to get the user events, and for some reason I get this exception. The funny thing is that the URL works great (tested it in a browser while debugging) and as mentioned - I use the same method in another place in my code to get something and it works. I'm completely losing it trying to figure out what's wrong!

Here's the code:

```
String accessToken = Session.getActiveSession().getAccessToken(); 
String query = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/events/attending?fields=id,name,location,venue,start_time,end_time,privacy&access_token=" + accessToken; 

HttpGet get = new HttpGet(query);
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();

try {
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(get);
    String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

JSONObject eventsJsonObj = new JSONObject(result); 

JSONArray eventsArray = eventsJsonObj.getJSONArray("data");

for (int i=0; i < eventsArray.length(); i++) {
    // do something with event 
}

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}
```

EDIT: here's the stack trace and the url as taken in debug and checked in browser (replacing of course the access token with [access_token]). btw, you can try the url yourself with an access token from the graph api explorer

URL: [https://graph.facebook.com/me/events/attending?fields=id,name,location,venue,start_time,end_time,privacy&access_token=[access_token]](https://graph.facebook.com/me/events/attending?fields=id,name,location,venue,start_time,end_time,privacy&access_token=%5baccess_token%5d)

06-17 15:07:17.684: W/System.err(22733): java.net.UnknownHostException
06-17 15:07:17.684: W/System.err(22733):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.getAllByName(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:272)
06-17 15:07:17.684: W/System.err(22733):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:153)
06-17 15:07:17.684: W/System.err(22733):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:167)
06-17 15:07:17.689: W/System.err(22733):    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:125)
06-17 15:07:17.689: W/System.err(22733):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.executeOriginal(DefaultRequestDirector.java:1171)
06-17 15:07:17.689: W/System.err(22733):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:637)
06-17 15:07:17.689: W/System.err(22733):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
06-17 15:07:17.689: W/System.err(22733):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
06-17 15:07:17.694: W/System.err(22733):    at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
06-17 15:07:17.694: W/System.err(22733):    at

Comment: Try to log your URL and then try that URL in browser. Does it works? Hope you have declared internet permission in your manifest.

Comment: use post method insted get...:)

Comment: Hi, thanks. 

@RaviBhatt - tried that. It works. Of course I gave internet permission.

Comment: @Hardik - tried it too. Still no luck…

Comment: Make sure your device is connected to internet..!!

Comment: @LiorZ please post full stack trace and try to encode url

Comment: ya got it but you must use post method because get not worked with fb....

Comment: I did. Changed it to post - still doesn't work… and btw, in someplace else I used get and it did work. I'm really confused by all of this.

Comment: @LiorZ in your device or your emulator internet must be working please check it.. opening device browser...

Comment: @LiorZ just click on this url https://graph.facebook.com/ you will get why you should use post method...

Comment: The url works perfectly in the device browser @Hardik

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of aggression towards Eclipse, I finally figured out the dumb (yet reasonable) mistake I made.

I called the request on the main thread, which is something everybody knows not to do. So that was the issue… if anyone ever runs into.

Facebook takes get requests.